# how can I uniques my object where has the same id and add the amount + 1?

Tags: javascript

I have an array with objects like this:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": "blue",
    "id": "1",
    "size": "S",
  },
  Object {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": "red",
    "id": "2",
    "size": "L",
  },
  Object {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": null,
    "id": "3",
    "size": null,
  },
  Object {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": "blue",
    "id": "1",
    "size": "S",
  },
  Object {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": "red",
    "id": "2",
    "size": "L",
  },
  Object {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": null,
    "id": "3",
    "size": null,
  },
  Object {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": "blue",
    "id": "1",
    "size": "S",
  },
  Object {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": "red",
    "id": "2",
    "size": "L",
  },
  Object {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": null,
    "id": "3",
    "size": null,
  },
  Object {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": "blue",
    "id": "1",
    "size": "S",
  },
  Object {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": "red",
    "id": "2",
    "size": "L",
  },
  Object {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": null,
    "id": "3",
    "size": null,
  },
  Object {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": "blue",
    "id": "1",
    "size": "S",
  },
  Object {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": "red",
    "id": "2",
    "size": "L",
  },
  Object {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": null,
    "id": "3",
    "size": null,
  },
]
```

How can I add all amounts +1 where has the same color and size and id, and removes the duplicated colors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one should work. I split it on two parts, so it is easier to understand.

```js
const src = [
  {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": "blue",
    "id": "1",
    "size": "S",
  },
  {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": "red",
    "id": "2",
    "size": "L",
  },
  {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": null,
    "id": "3",
    "size": null,
  },
  {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": "blue",
    "id": "1",
    "size": "S",
  },
  {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": "red",
    "id": "2",
    "size": "L",
  },
  {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": null,
    "id": "3",
    "size": null,
  },
  {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": "blue",
    "id": "1",
    "size": "S",
  },
  {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": "red",
    "id": "2",
    "size": "L",
  },
  {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": null,
    "id": "3",
    "size": null,
  },
  {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": "blue",
    "id": "1",
    "size": "S",
  },
  {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": "red",
    "id": "2",
    "size": "L",
  },
  {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": null,
    "id": "3",
    "size": null,
  },
  {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": "blue",
    "id": "1",
    "size": "S",
  },
  {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": "red",
    "id": "2",
    "size": "L",
  },
  {
    "amount": 1,
    "color": null,
    "id": "3",
    "size": null,
  },
];

const amountsByKey = src.reduce((collector, item) => {
    const item_key = JSON.stringify({ id: item.id, color: item.color, size: item.size });
    collector[item_key] = item.amount + (collector[item_key] | 0);
    return collector;
  }, {});
const result = Object.entries(amountsByKey).map(([key, value]) => ({
  ...JSON.parse(key),
  amount: value,
}));
console.log(result);
```